# Create p4 client spec in shell script

Tags: shell, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I am trying to automate creation of p4 client spec and synching all directories for our application in shell script.

```
function setup_perforce {
    hostname=`hostname`
    echo "export P4PORT=xxx" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export P4CLIENT=xxx_yyyy_$hostname" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export P4USER=xxx" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "export P4PASSWD=xxx" >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc
    p4 trust -y
    p4 login -s
    p4 client

   //sync directories
   p4 sync //xxxxx
   p4 sync //yyyyy
}
```

When I run this script it is stopping at "p4 client" asking to save/verify created client spec in /tmp/xxx. But I want to run this script without any approvals or external input from user. I don't see any option available for p4 client command.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a non-interactive editor, or a dummy command like `/bin/true`:

```
EDITOR=/bin/true p4 client
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `p4 client -i` you can pipe your client spec into this command or redirect from a file using `<`. The `-i` switch reads the client spec from standard input.

Comment: If you're in the right root directory, and all the other workspace defaults are adequate, 'p4 client -o | p4 client -i' is the easiest way to create your workspace.